# How does one convert PSVirtualMachineObjects?

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine, workflow

I'm trying to deploy Azure VM's thru a workflow so it could be done in parallel. The code works fine outside of a workflow. But getting this error when trying to do it thru a workflow.

I'm importing the VM parameters thru a csv file. 
Are there additional considerations for deploying Azure VM's thru a Workflow?

```
Workflow Deploy-VMs {
    $cred1= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "User",$(ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -asplaintext -force)
    $b=Import-Csv Y:\NLG\vms1.csv -Verbose|? type -eq 'VM'
    foreach ($c in $b) {
        AzureRM.Resources\Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred1 -SubscriptionId subscription id
        $nic = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $c.Name -ResourceGroupName nlg -Location $c.Location -SubnetId $c.SubnetID 
        $cred= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "nladmin",$(ConvertTo-SecureString $c.Password -asplaintext -force)
        $vmConfig = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $c.Name -VMSize "Standard_D1" 
        $vmConfig = Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $vmConfig  -Windows -ComputerName $c.Name -Credential $cred 
        $vmConfig = Set-AzureRmVMSourceImage -VM $vmConfig -PublisherName "MicrosoftWindowsServer" -Offer "WindowsServer" -Skus "2012-R2-Datacenter-smalldisk" -Version "latest" 
        $vmConfig = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vmConfig -Id $nic.Id
        $vmConfig = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vmConfig -Name $c.Name -CreateOption FromImage
        New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $c.RG -Location $c.Location -VM $vmConfig
    }
}
```

and getting this error

> Cannot bind parameter 'VM'. Cannot convert value
>   "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Models.PSVirtualMachine" to type
>   "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Models.PSVirtualMachine". Error:
>   "Cannot convert the
>   "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Models.PSVirtualMachine" value of 
>   type
>   "Deserialized.Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Models.PSVirtualMachine"
>   to type "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Models.PSVirtualMachine"."
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.SetAzureVMOperatingSystemCommand
>       + PSComputerName        : [localhost]

Comment: did you try updating powershell modules?

Comment: Yes. Doesn't help. I'm using Powershell v5.1

Comment: I test in my lab. I get the same result with you. Maybe you could use the [example](https://blogs.inframon.com/2016/09/deploy-in-parallel-multiple-azure-virtual-machines-powershell-workflow-script/) to create VM in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved using inline script for the incompatible cmdlets.

```
Workflow Deploy-VMs {
    $cred1 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "User", $(ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force)
    $b = Import-Csv Y:\NLG\vms1.csv -Verbose|? type -eq 'VM'
    foreach -Parallel ($c in $b) {
        AzureRM.Resources\Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred1 -SubscriptionId c2d7e81b-ed6a-4de9-a4cd-36e679ec4259
        $nic = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $c.Name -ResourceGroupName nlg -Location $c.Location -SubnetId $c.SubnetID 
        $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "nladmin", $(ConvertTo-SecureString $c.Password -AsPlainText -Force)
        InlineScript {
            $vmConfig = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $using:c.Name -VMSize "Standard_D1" 
            $vmConfig = Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $vmConfig  -Windows -ComputerName $using:c.Name -Credential $using:cred 
            $vmConfig = Set-AzureRmVMSourceImage -VM $vmConfig -PublisherName "MicrosoftWindowsServer" -Offer "WindowsServer" -Skus "2012-R2-Datacenter-smalldisk" -Version "latest" 
            $vmConfig = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vmConfig -Id $using:nic.Id
            $vmConfig = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vmConfig -Name $using:c.Name -CreateOption FromImage
            New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $using:c.RG -Location $using:c.Location -VM $vmConfig
        }
    }
}
```